# Redirect and display image

Tags: php

```
HTTP://BYE.ORG/INDEX.PHP

    $image = 'http://hello.com/img.gif';
    header('Content-type: image/gif');
    readfile($image);
    header('Location: http://example.com/index.php'); *
```

I have the above php file hosted on index.php

Basically, when I visit bye.org/index.php I want to redirect to example.com/index.php, then display the image hello.com/img.gif

If I put the line with asterisk at the bottom, the redirect works but the image isn't displayed. If I put it at the top, the image is displayed but redirect doesn't work anymore.

It's possible to do both things (first do redirect, then display image)?

Thank you

Comment: This will not work. You cannot issue a header() AFTER you've performed output, and the image would never be displayed anyways, since the browser would be off fetching the new url.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to redirect and then display the image on the other page.

You can use Javascript to change the URL in the addressbar without reloading the page, though.

Try running this in the console in this page

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

I don't think you'll be able to display the image with the image headers and have JS running on the page, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=156500) using JS, as you will not be able to do this with PHP.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function Doredirect()
{
window.location = 'LANDINGPAGE.htm';
}

</script>

<img onload='javascript:Doredirect()' src="image.png" width="1" height="1" alt=" "> 
</body>
```

Comment: He tagged his question with PHP?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I commented he's not able to do this with PHP?

Comment: What is wrong with using `$_SESSION['show_image'] = '$image.png';` and then on config (or file that always loads) check it like this: `if ( isset($_SESSION['show_image']) ) { $image = $_SESSION['show_image']); unset($_SESSION['show_image']); }` and then somewhere on the page you could show the image with just printing out $image to the `img` tag. It will work only once. That would do the job?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev If you feel that it will work, you can submit it as an answer.

Comment: Wait if it's the other domain, then it will not work like I was thinking. Missed the part with two different domains.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to display image and redirect after some seconds . but in php , as i know you can not send two diff header together with php .